# Add String of TSearchrec to Memo

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe3, memo

I want to add the files in the selected folder to the memobox or in a stringlist and show the results. In both ways, i can add them but i can't show the files from the folder in the memo or from the stringlist in a `ShowMessage`-dialog.

```
function CountFilesInFolder(AFolder: String; AMask: String): Integer;
var 
  tmp1: TSearchRec;
  ergebnis: Integer;
  memo1: string;
  list : TStringList;
begin
  result := 0;
  if (AFolder <> '') then
  begin
    if AFolder[length(AFolder)] <> '\' then AFolder := AFolder + '\';
    ergebnis := FindFirst(AFolder + AMask, faArchive + faReadOnly + faHidden + faSysFile, tmp1);
      while ergebnis = 0 do
      begin
        Inc(result);
        ergebnis := FindNext(tmp1);
        while ((tmp1.Name = '|*_tif.tif')) and (ergebnis <> 0) do
        ergebnis := FindNext(tmp1);
      end;
       list.Add(tmp1.Name);
       FindClose(tmp1);
  end;
end;
```

thank you for your time and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `Memo1.Lines.Add(tmp1.Name);` adds the filenames to your memo. Better to pass the memo in the function call though. BTW, your `list` is local in scope and not used properly. It has to be created before use (and freed after use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A low-level function like this should not directly add items to a memo. Instead pass a `TStrings` (an abstraction of a string list) into the function and fill it:

```
function CountFilesInFolder(AFolder: String; AMask: String; FileNames: TStrings): Integer;
begin
// do your file enumeration
// for each file call FileNames.Add(FileName);
end;
```

Since the `Lines` property of a memo is also of type `TStrings` you can use it directly like this:

```
CountFilesInFolder('D:\', '*.TXT', Memo1.Lines);
```

If you wanted to have the filenames in a string list, the usual pattern goes like this:

```
FileNames := TStringList.Create;
try
  CountFilesInFolder('D:\', '*.TXT', FileNames);
finally
  FileNames.Free;
end;
```

The important point is that the caller creates and destroys the `TStringList` passed into `CountFilesInFolder` - an important principle in Delphi.